# How to add embedded YouTube video at the end of ViewSlideshow

Tags: views, 6, javascript, nodes

I have a Slideshow view which loads two fields, **main images** ('group multiple values' unchecked to create rows) and **video** ('hide if empty' checked). It takes these from one node which it gets from the nid argument.

The slideshow currently displays 13 images but each image also has a seperate instance of the video attached to it.

I've tried playing about with the views-slideshow.tpl.php file and I've also tried excluding the video from display then manipulating the view ovject from withing hook_views_prerender() and hook_preprocess_views_view(), all with no luck.

I just want the 13 unique images with the single instance of the video link added to the end, therefore creating 14 unique slides. Ideally I would want to add 2 or 3 videos so the solution needs to account for this.

Comment: basically you want a slide with 13 images and the last one is a video, right?

Comment: are you using a slideshow plugin? if so which one? it's a bit confusing that the video turns up 13 times! what happens if you display the view in a flat unformatted list on a separate page/block

Comment: At the moment i've looped through the view in views_pre_render and unset the video related keys from each row, then ive added these as an additional row on the end. It works except 1. I get an empty slide because views_pre_render goes through every view twice(why?!?) and 2. It's obviously no solution for multiple videos

Comment: For the record 14 is blank, 15 is the video. It goes through ALL views on the site twice, not just this one.

Answer (score 0):

- first tick exclude from display for video field
- then create view tpl (check view -> edit > theme information for suggestion and markup
- then manually include an `<li></li>` at just after loop
- -inside `<li></li>` , echo the video field name, mostly its something like this `$rows[0][VIDEOFIELDNAME]`